# Error : Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Stop Execution of Container/Cloud Run once execution of Python is done

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

My requirement is to stop the execution of Cloud run/container once the execution of python code is complete.
The task is to fetch files from Cloud Storage, process them and then export them back to cloud storage.
I am able to complete the task successfully. But the cloud build is ending with below error.

"deploy-to-cloud-run": ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more info.

CloudBuild.yml

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/reponame:latest', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/reponame:$COMMIT_SHA', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/reponame:$BUILD_ID', '.']
  id: 'build-image-reponame'
  waitFor: ['-']  # The '-' indicates that this step begins immediately.
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['push', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/reponame:$COMMIT_SHA']
  id: 'push-image-to-container-registry'
  waitFor: ['build-image-reponame']
- name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
  entrypoint: gcloud
  args:
  - 'run'
  - 'deploy'
  - 'reponame'
  - '--image'
  - 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/reponame:$COMMIT_SHA'
  - '--region'
  - 'us-east1'
  - '--platform'
  - 'managed'

  waitFor: ['push-image-to-container-registry']
  id: 'deploy-to-cloud-run'
images:
- 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/reponame:latest'
- 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/reponame:$COMMIT_SHA'
- 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/reponame:$BUILD_ID'
```

Comment: As you errors says, the problem is that your container crashed on startup. This is super hard to debug without further logs. It might be due to credentials, but it might be something completely different.

Comment: Run your container (or your code) in Cloud Build, and run a Cloud Build build when you want to execute your code. Or wrap your code in an HTTP server. Anyway, explain deeper your use case, and what you want to achieve if you want a better design for that use case

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere  We are fetching data from S3 bucket may be CSV/Parquet files doing Data Normalization, Cleaning part and then purging the processed files back to S3 bucket. So no UI part involved here. In Gist we have to 1. pull data 2 process it 3. push back to s3 bucket. Thanks!

Comment: @SimonHawe Logs : Ready condition status changed to False for Revision repename with message: Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.
After printing print statements in python code it is exiting with below error. 
Container called exit(0).

Comment: Agree, no UI, but I didn't mentioned UI, I just said webserver. Cloud Run serve only HTTP traffic, you can't run batch job as you do. Create a HTTP rest API, on each request, run your different step and answer gracefully the request. Note that CPU is allocated to Cloud Run only with a request is being processed.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere could you please provide me with some reference or any example on how to achieve this. I have simple one python file(.py) with couple of functions which talks to s3 and process data. Thanks!!

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Thanks for all your help. It is not giving any error now but we have a scenario here the code will get executed only when we are going to hit this url provided by the cloud run. We want this to be executed once the pipeline starts. Could you please suggest some idea over this?

Comment: You have 2 solutions: Either you perform a CURL to your API from Cloud Build to run the process at the beginning of the pipeline, or you put your code directly in the pipeline (why don't you execute the process in a step?)

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere sorry but how to achieve the same in one step? Do you mean to use shellscrip?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I made code to be moved out of function and executed them on first call. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply rely on the [getting started tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/python)

For your code, do something like this (code get from the tutorial with some comments)

```
import os

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    #name = os.environ.get("NAME", "World")
    #return "Hello {}!".format(name)
    # Put your logic here
    return "Done", 200 #return nicely the response to the request


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 8080)))
```

Then when you want to run your processing, call the / route and the process will be performed. That's all. If the processing take more than 3 minutes, you can increase the cloud run timeout up to 60 minutes.